# "If all" in handlebars js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working with handlebars.js(hbs), I haven't fully learned it but I was wondering if there is such thing as something like

```
{{#if all source}}
```

if not then how would I go about making something around if all?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: For example, 
{{#if all hidden}}
<h1>hidden</h1>
{{else}}
<h1>Shown</h1>
{{/if}}

Comment: What is `all` and what is `hidden`?

Comment: all would be like `#ifall` or `#if all`, and `hidden` is just an example variable.

Comment: Then I don't see why this wouldn't work with just `{{#if truthyVariable}}...{{/if}}`.

Comment: For example, in this project I am working on its seeing if a card is hidden via Mongodb then don't show it, but if all the cards are hidden (which could be more than one) than it wouldn't display any text as of right now. It would just be blank, do you have any recommendations on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: It seems like you have left details out of your question. I think your question is: How can I perform some logic in Handlebars to determine if every value in an Array meets some condition? I think the simplest way would be to add a property to your template data, like `allHidden`, and evaluate it _before_ rendering the template. Something like `allHidden: source.every(item => item.hidden)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [76484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397771/76484) said:
 
It seems like you have left details out of your question. I think your question is: How can I perform some logic in Handlebars to determine if every value in an Array meets some condition? I think the simplest way would be to add a property to your template data, like `allHidden`, and evaluate it before rendering the template. Something like:

```
allHidden: source.every(item => item.hidden)
```

Thanks for the help!